# ColdFusion Deleting a session variable

Tags: session, coldfusion, session-variables, coldfusion-9

I I've done a lot of looking around for code that'll delete a session variable, and the close I've got to success is with this:

```
<cfset StructDelete(Session,"username")>
```

It works the first time, then it never works again. I've spent the past hour on this and am going insane, any help would be much appreciated.

I'm not sure if this is related but when I modify a .cfm for some reason it doesn't always seem to "update" instantly. What I mean is, I'd change a page, access it and it won't use the new code. This is a horror when trying to debug...

Comment: That's a proper way to delete a session variable. If it's coming back, then you're setting it again somewhere or changing sessions. For your caching problem, I'd look to see if Trusted Cache is on.

Comment: You should separate your questions into different posts.

Comment: "It never works again" - what does it do (or not do)? Throw an error? Simply not delete the key?

Comment: @Busches Trust cache is off, save class files too.

Comment: @Jake Feasel I've got it so that every time I run the code it redirects to a page where the session is output. Technically speaking, it shouldn't output anything, but it does.

Comment: Have you tried dumping out the session scope immediately after the StructDelete? If so, are you seeing the "username" key in that dump?

Comment: Where is this code running?  Within a .cfc or just a line on a .cfm page?

Comment: @Jake Feasel Yes I'm dumping and it's there. I changed the code so that before it deletes the session, it changes its value. It worked once and didn't work again, some how I get the feeling the cache is related. I should mention that the page with this code has a header redirect

Comment: @Sharondio In a cfm file

Comment: IF you "delete" as session and then redirect all the "onsessionstart()" code will run again.... right? so you just get a new session. Is the sessionid changing with each request?

Comment: Downvoted because the initial question is too vaguely worded to sensibly answer, and there's a second question asked as well.  Will remove downvote (and try to asnwer the question!) if these things are mitigated.

Comment: @AdamCameron The first question is perfectly clear and I only added the second because I thought the errors maybe related.

Comment: Mate, if it was perfectly clear then me 'n' Jake wouldn't have both suggested it could stand clarification: "It never works again" - what does it do (or not do)? Throw an error? Simply not delete the key?  And there's clearly NOT enough info because in just the situation you describe, the code works fine.  So you need to elaborate. On the info you've given, the best you'll get is "well that should work", and people just guessing.

Comment: @AdamCameron There is nothing else to say, it just doesn't work again. Hence why I added the only other error I'm having in case it is related.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you mean it's coming back into existence and you think it should be gone. Look for any "cfparams" that set the variable. It might be deleted then reinitiated on the next request.

You can also add a boolean to check if it exists when you delete it.

```
<cfset exists= structdelete(session, 'username', true)/>
```

This will give you a "yes" if it exists and a "no" if it doesn't - allowing you to execute further logic if you wish.

You might also take a look at your application names, session timeout values onsessionStart() etc. I've seen problems where a new session was being instantiated with each request.

Comment: Where are you setting this variable in the first place?  I think Mark is on the right trail with it being reset right after you delete it.

Comment: Sharondio - are you currently working a contract? Are in Eastern VA.? Currently working a contract?  (looking for resources on the East coast at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

I just cfset the session variable to kill it...

```
 <cfset session.allowin = "False">
```

And the application.cfm file is always looking for true...